# Run Kivy App and still see the Battery and time and other icons

Tags: android, python-2.7, kivy

Is there a way to run a Kivy application on Android (whether from Kivy launcher or compiled to a stand alone application) and still see the battery, carrier signal, wifi signal, notification icons...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Certainly, you just need to compile it as a windowed application (rather than the default, which is fullscreen). You can do this by passing `--window` to `build.py` if using python-for-android to compile, or by setting `fullscreen = 0` in your buildozer.spec if using the buildozer tool.

You probably can't easily do this from the kivy launcher, since it seems to be compiled as a fullscreen app, but it's easy for any kivy apk you build yourself.

You can see a list of the other python-for-android options [here](http://python-for-android.readthedocs.org/en/latest/toolchain/#step-2-package-your-application), which might be useful to you.

Also, if you haven't seen it before, [buildozer](https://github.com/kivy/buildozer) is a useful tool that automates the entire android build process (or ios, though that's less mature right now), and lets you configure everything via a config file.

Comment: Thanks @inclement! You always save the day! so to build.py i should add -- window OK that's easy but should I precise here the size of it like --window 800x480 or so?

Comment: No, there are only really two options - fullscreen (as you have now) or windowed (just slightly smaller to not cover the status bar).